# Failed to load config "plugin:vue/no-layout-rules" to extend from

Tags: npm, vuejs2, eslint

I keep getting the error in the title when i try build or serve the vuejs build. Not quite sure on what "no-layout-rules" is about. The only reference to it that I could find was on eslint repo here: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/master/vue.js.

```
odule.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "@vue/prettier"],
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off"
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  }
};
```

Comment: Well, I just downloaded a project which came with this error. I got rid of it by simply commenting *everything* inside `.eslintrc.js` out. Not a real solution, but hey, it works!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that "no-layout-rules" means that the build is missing dependencies.

In my case, after removing "@vue/prettier" from my config NPM right away pointed out which dependencies I was missing.

Once I have installed missing dependencies I was able to reinstate "@vue/prettier"; everything worked fine from there onwards.